# How do I see that $\{c \in I : 0 \le c \le b, y(c)=1\}$ has a minimum?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $y$ is differentiable on $\mathbb R$ and $y(0)=2$. Suppose further that there is a $b>0$ such that $y(b)<1$.

How do I see that $\{c \in I : 0 \le c \le b, y(c)=1\}$ has a minimum ?

I see that it isn't empty by the mean value theorem ?

Comment: HINT: this is a non-empty compact set, so it has a minimum.

Comment: what do you mean by compact ?

Comment: @user111854 oh, well. If you don't know what compactness is, answering this question will be a little difficult.

Comment: It is my understanding $b$ is a fixed real number greater than zero

Comment: @Crostul Yes, that's why I deleted my comment. Perhaps it's only me but I think the way it is written is highly misleading. Thanks.

Comment: @Timbuc: I agree with you that it is misleading. I edited it.

Comment: @user111854 At least you can see the set is closed *and* bounded? Do you know The Weierstrass theorems about continuous functions on closed, bounded intervals?

Answer (score 1):

Let's call this set $K$. By the intermediate value theorem there exists some $c \in [0,b]$ such that $y(c)=1$, so $K$ is non-empty. Moreover $K\subset [0,b]$, so it is bounded. Call $m= \inf K$.

By definition of $\inf$ there exists some sequence $\{ x_n \} \subset K$ converging to $m$. Since the sequence is inside $K$, you have $y(x_n)=1$ for all $n$.

Finally, since $y$ is a continuous function, you have $y(x_n) \to y(m)$, so that $y(m)=1$. This means that $m \in K$, hence it is a minimum.

Comment: [Mean value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) or [intermediate value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem)?

Comment: @Regret Sorry, I meant the IVT. Thanks.

Comment: I made a slight edit to your answer. Feel free to revert it if you are uncomfortable with it, but I think it makes your answer a bit more concise.